# Function inside provider not recognized by Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, karma-mocha, angular-providers

First a little background on what I want to achieve. I have a service that requires some configuration before it gets injected and used. After doing some research I figured that having a provider for the service would be the best solution. So I implemented the provider according to [this example](http://www.timecockpit.com/devblog/2014/10/24/AngularJS-Provider-in-TypeScript). Even thought the Typescript compiler (I'm using typescript to compile my code into valid JavaScript) thinks it's oké, JavaScript does not recognize the function that's available through the provider to set some options.

My code looks as follows (some code has been left out or renamed for a reason)

```
export interface ICustomServiceProvider extends ng.IServiceProvider {
  setOptions(options: ICustomOptions): void;
  $get($http, $window, $resource): ICustomService;
}

class CustomServiceProvider implements ICustomServiceProvider {
  private options: ICustomOptions;

  public $get($http, $window, $resource) {
    return new CustomService($http, $window, $resource);
  }

  public setOptions(options: ICustomOptions): void {
    this.options = options;
  }
}

angular.module('custom', ['ngResource'])
  .service('CustomService', CustomService)
  .provider('CustomService', CustomServiceProvider);
```

The problem occurs when using the provider in one of my unit tests (I'm using Karma with Mocka for testing) and calling the `setOptions` function. Which is done like this.

```
describe('CustomService', function() {

  var provider: ICustomServiceProvider;
  var options: {hello: 'world'};

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService) {
    provider = <ICustomServiceProvider> $injector.get('');
  }));

  it('CustomService provider test', function() {
    provider.setOptions(options);
  });
}
```

When running this test Karma throws an error saying

> TypeError: provider.setOptions is not a function at Context.[anonymous]

Also the compiled JavaScript Visual Studio Code is giving me a green warning (I don't think it's a error) on the provider variable on the line `.provider('CustomService', CustomServiceProvider);`

> Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IServiceProvider'. Property '$get' is missing in type '() => void'.
>   (local var) CustomServiceProvider: () => void
>   Providers

I already spent hours on fixing this problem but cannot seem to find the solution. Any idea on how to fix this of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit (30-09-2015)**

The service I'm am talking about looks like this:

```
export interface ICustomService {
  // Some function definitions
}

class CustomService implements ICustomService {
  static $inject = ['$http', '$window', '$resource'];

  constructor(httpService: ng.IHttpService, windowService: ng.IWindowService, resourceService: ng.resource.IResourceService, options: ICustomOptions) {
    // Setting variables
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here, IHMO, is the fact that your are trying to register a service & a provider with the same name (`CustomService`). You don't have to do this.

In your case, it seems that you just have to register the provider. Rename your `CustomServiceProvider` class to `CustomService`, then change your last lines of code to just:

```
angular
    .module('custom', ['ngResource'])
    .provider('CustomService', CustomService);
```

This way, in the `config` phase of your app, you will be able to inject `CustomServiceProvider` (and use `setOptions`), but also `CustomService` in controllers, directives & other services.

Please read [Angular Documentation on providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) (mainly "Provider Recipe") for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can just rename it. I already do have a class with the name 'CustomService' which gets created and returned by the provider. Also... do they have the be different, as I've seen examples where the naming of the service and provider was identical. Angular would then insert the 'provider' part for you.